# Opt group label given and option value given option value will be reflected in Fee field i want is opt group label has to be shown in print

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label>4. Type:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="drive_type">
                <option >Select</option>
                 <optgroup label="Petrol">
                     <option value="30">Petrol - 2W</option>
                     <option value="50">Petrol - 3W</option>
                     <option value="50">Petrol - 4W</option>
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="Diesel">
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 2W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 3W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 4W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 8W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 10W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 11W</option>
                     <option value="60">Diesel - 16W</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
$('select[name="drive_type"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="poll_test_fee"]').val($(this).val());
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific and also don't put the entire question in the title.

Comment: I want the <option value="30">Petrol - 2W</option> petrol - 2W to be printed in the print page along with value and optgroup. you can see the

Answer (score 0):

Here's working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzpkta0o/).

You nearly got that working, you just didn't need parenthesis after listener.

An if correctly understood, I added `optgroup` name in fiddle too, which can be extracted this way in listener.

```
$(this).find('option:selected').parents('optgroup').attr('label')
```

Comment: In this html code option object has to be print along with opt group label,  and opt value.

Comment: @HariSankar It does print optgroup label and option value